# How to use multiple if condition in project

Tags: javascript, php, html

Thank you for the helps. I am middle of a proble and I am n't able to solve this simple problem. Please help me.

my code is :-

```
<?php 

        $sel="select * from demo1 where paper_type='Quantitative'"; 
        $exe=mysql_query($sel);
        while($rt=mysql_fetch_array($exe))
        {
            $array_val[]=$rt['condition'];  
        }

    ?>
<script>

    var val1 = "<?php echo($array_val[0]); ?>";
    var val2 = "<?php echo($array_val[1]); ?>";
    var val3 = "<?php echo($array_val[2]); ?>";
    var val4 = "<?php echo($array_val[3]); ?>";
    var val5 = "<?php echo($array_val[5]); ?>";

    if(val1 == "a" )
    {
        document.getElementById("imgClick1").src = "images/a.jpg";
        document.getElementById('num1').style.color = "#000";
    }
    else if(val1 == "b")
    {   document.getElementById("imgClick1").src = "images/b.jpg";
        document.getElementById('num1').style.color = "#fff";
    }
    if(val2 == "a" )
    {
        document.getElementById("imgClick2").src = "images/a.jpg";
        document.getElementById('num2').style.color = "#000";
    }
    else if(val2 == "b")
    {
        document.getElementById("imgClick2").src = "images/b.jpg";
        document.getElementById('num2').style.color = "#fff";
    }
    if(val3 == "a" )
    {
        document.getElementById("imgClick3").src = "images/a.jpg";
        document.getElementById('num3').style.color = "#000";
    }
    else if(val3 == "b")
    {
        document.getElementById("imgClick3").src = "images/b.jpg";
        document.getElementById('num3').style.color = "#fff";
    }
</script>
```

Using php I get the value from MySQL to php array '$array_val[]' and place the value into javascript variable but when I am trying to check it by using if condition, it just working on the first if condition.

please help me, how I can use the other if condition also?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by just working on the first if condition?,

Also, can you provide what val1,val2, and val3 are set to?  You can just write those variables to the console to see them after you run your script.

Comment: `var val = <?php echo json_encode($array_val); ?>;` and then to display:   `.src = 'images/' + encodeURICompomnent(val[0]) + '.jpg'`

Comment: You shoud probably do an "alert(val)" for each of your variables, the content of each one of them may not be what you expect.

Comment: If you get a view source, do you see the proper values be assigned to `val1` to `val5` ?

Comment: Generally avoid to double code in conditions; try to bring the cases to a common form and apply the single, generalized code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In such case I'l recomment using JSON.

Check following solution implemented using JSON for your problem.

```
var json=JSON.parse('<?php echo json_encode($array_val)?>');

//process your json array here

for(key in json){  //for each elements in json array

     //default image and color
     var image_src = "images/default.jpg";
     var color = "#aaa";

      switch(json[key]){
        case "a":{
                  //code for a
                  image_src = "images/a.jpg";
                  color = "#000";
                  break;
        }
        case "b":{
                  //code for b
                  image_src = "images/b.jpg";
                  color = "#fff";
                  break;
        }
      }

      document.getElementById("imgClick"+(key+1)).src=image_src; // it will generate imgClick1, imgClick2 selectors and so on.. for each element of json
      document.getElementById("num"+(key+1)).style.color=color; // it will generate num1, num2 selectors and so on.. for each element of json
}
```

**EDIT: Solution to your original code**

Test for `$array_val[index]` before echo, so that it will `echo` only if its value is defined.

In this case it will make value of `valN` variable to `""` blank string, so that it will not match for either `"a"` or `"b"`. (You might want to specify some default case here in else case if value is not defined)

```
var val1 = "<?php if(isset($array_val[0]) echo $array_val[0] ?>"; //you might add here else echo "a"; to specify some default value.
var val2 = "<?php if(isset($array_val[1]) echo $array_val[1] ?>";
var val3 = "<?php if(isset($array_val[2]) echo $array_val[2] ?>";
var val4 = "<?php if(isset($array_val[3]) echo $array_val[3] ?>";
var val5 = "<?php if(isset($array_val[4]) echo $array_val[4] ?>";

if(val1 == "a" )
{
    document.getElementById("imgClick1").src = "images/a.jpg";
    document.getElementById('num1').style.color = "#000";
}
else if(val1 == "b")
{   document.getElementById("imgClick1").src = "images/b.jpg";
    document.getElementById('num1').style.color = "#fff";
}

if(val2 == "a" )
{
    document.getElementById("imgClick2").src = "images/a.jpg";
    document.getElementById('num2').style.color = "#000";
}
else if(val2 == "b")
{
    document.getElementById("imgClick2").src = "images/b.jpg";
    document.getElementById('num2').style.color = "#fff";
}

if(val3 == "a" )
{
    document.getElementById("imgClick3").src = "images/a.jpg";
    document.getElementById('num3').style.color = "#000";
}
else if(val3 == "b")
{
    document.getElementById("imgClick3").src = "images/b.jpg";
    document.getElementById('num3').style.color = "#fff";
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't use jQuery in your answer unless the asker specifically tags the question with jQuery or use it themself in their example code.

Comment: I'd recommend to take the src = ... assignments out of the condition and just assign to variable like: image = "images/a.jpg"; and color = "#000"; - also with var image and var color with senseful defaults. (Is it nice style to edit other's answers in such way?)

Comment: Ofcourse, you can edit others answer if you found something useful to add. Reviewer will later review the edit :)

Comment: I believe your answer simplifies the solution but doesn't address the true problem being presented. The source of the problem must lie in the query result or the HTML source being manipulated by the JS code.  If you address the real issue, I'll vote up.  Start by adding null checks and check query result count against expected count of 5+.